# Alternate Definition(s) for (Ir)regular Primes

Tags: nt.number-theory

Are there any definitions for (ir)regular primes which do **not** use class number divisibility or Bernoulli numbers? For reference, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_prime) gives both the first definition (their primary one) and the second (*i.e.*, Kummer’s criterion, using Bernoulli numbers).

I'm looking for a third (or more) fundamentally different characterization — bonus points if it can be stated and proven in an elementary (if not necessarily simple) way. Here's a conjectured example: A prime $p$ is *irregular* if and only if there exists some even integer $2 \le n \le p-3$ such that
$$
  p^2 \mid (1^n + 2^n + \dotsb + (p-1)^n + p^n).
$$

Comment: Are you looking for something other than "$p$ is regular if $p$ does not divide the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$, where $\zeta_p$ is a $p$-th root of unity"?

Comment: Hi David,
Yes, I'm looking for something else -- I’m sorry I wasn’t more clear in my original posting.

Wikipedia <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_prime> gives both your definition (their primary definition) and Kummer’s criterion (with Bernoulli numbers). I was wondering if anyone since Kummer has found a third (or more) equivalent criterion or definition.

Thanks!
Kieren.

Comment: Are you looking for a connection with some other circle of ideas? The fact that the $p$-part of the class group of the $p$th cyclotomic field is related to values of the Riemann zeta function is already pretty cool. Also, I would define $p$ to be regular as David Speyer, has, and everything else would be a "theorem" not a "definition".

Comment: We can just keep translating into different language.  How about "The reduced $K_0$ of the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ is $p$-divisible"?

Comment: Hi Rob,

Good distinction! So I'm looking for more *theorems* of the "Kummer Criterion" sort—and more "radical" than simply translating into different language (as pointed out by the next poster).

For example — and this is totally off the top of my head — it seems like Wolstenholme's Theorem(s) could be a starting point to prove a related fact about the divisibility of power sums, at which point the connection to the Bernoulli numbers and/or $p$-th roots of unity. But I can’t seem to find any mention of such an attempt anywhere in the literature.

Thanks!
Kieren

Comment: To be clear[er]: I've found papers in which Wolstenholme's Theorem(s) and Bernoulli numbers and/or irregular primes were discussed simultaneously, but I've never found a concerted effort — successful or otheriwse — to provide an alternative definition of irregular primes using WT.

Comment: It seems to me that, using the summation formula for consecutive powers (Faulhaber's formula), your "conjectured example" is equivalent to the definition of the divisibility of Bernoulli numbers. I would not call this a new definition.

Comment: Your comment is true _unless_ my conjecture can be proven with other [non-Bernoulli-number] means. Of course, that seems unlikely, given the strong equivalence. In any case, my original question is still open. I still feel that the Wolstenholme connection is the strongest lead I've thought of to date.

Answer (score 1):

David Frank, Irregular primes and integrality theorems for manifolds, Comment. Math. Helv. 50 (1975), no. 3, 321–326, MR0407856 (53 #11626): from the review, by K H Mayer, we have,

For any $p$ the following are equivalent: (i) $p$ is an irregular prime and (ii) for some $k>1$ there exists a manifold $M$ of dimension $4k$ satisfying the integrality conditions with order $\Sigma_{M^b}$ divisible by $p$.

I'm afraid you'll have to read the review to see what "the integrality conditions" are.

Also of possible interest is Tauno Metsänkylä, Maillet's matrix and irregular primes, Studies in honour of Arto Kustaa Salomaa on the occasion of his fiftieth birthday, Ann. Univ. Turku. Ser. A I No. 186 (1984), 72–79, MR0748520 (85j:11145). Here the rank of a certain matrix is given in terms of the irregularity index of a prime.